# Avoid creating full-package field in Intelij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When I have field, which is not created at the moment time, I usually hit alt + enter and do -> Create field

The problem is, when I create field, I have full package field, for example
com.blabla.ClassName, but I want to create field without package prefix.

Comment: Do you have types with same classname from different packages? eg. java.util.Date, java.mypack.Date etc?

Comment: Yeap, they are different

Answer (score 0):

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports

**Then select: Never, use short name and add import**

[image]